# useEffect, useState and promises.. what to do

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, use-effect

I'm having trouble at the moment of getting these values. First, I have a token that I have to retrieve via SecureStore, for these I do it with `useState`, then I have an async function called `getData(id)`, this id is used to query an `API`. I have to do 3 of these calls to 3 diferent id's, the data I get from the API I passed it to state hook called `qo`.

I use the useEffect hook for the first render to get the token, after that the second useEffect, that reacts to the token state, I call the getData funcion, but when it renders, it only shows 1 result of the other.

Code

```js
const [st, onSt] = useState("");
const [qo, onQo] = useState([]);

const getValue = async() => {
  let result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("ST");
  if (result) {
    onSt(result);
  }
};

const getData = async(id) => {
  return fetch(`https: //URL.COM/api/card/${id}`, {
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then((ans) => ans.json())
    .then((json) => {
      const obje = json.result_metadata[0].fingerprint.type;
      const tip = obje["type/Number"];
      onQo([
        ...qo,
        {
          title: json.name,
          value: tipo.max,
          author: json.creator.common_name,
        },
      ]);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};

useEffect(() => {
  getValue();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  getUser();
  getData(2272);
  getData(2273);
  getData(2274);
}, [st]);
```

I tried different useState but it is not a good solution

Comment: Newlines are nice :)

Comment: OP, there was a typo (bad template string for the URL) that I fixed, and I tidied up the code so that it's readable. Welcome to SO, btw.

Comment: Please see the above duplicate. `qo` is stale. Easily resolved with a functional update

Comment: Use functional update like others have said `onQo(qo => [...qo, { title: ..., value: ..., author: ... }])`